# Sum alphanumeric cells in a column Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum

I have a column that I would like to sum all numbers within. Each cell within the column starts with a string in the beginning:

BL1.00
HB1.00
HP0.50
HF0.25
LP1.00

=3.75

Some cells have 2 decimal points, how do I sum this column all the way to the 2 decimals?

Comment: So, **all** cells begin with 2 characters, which need to be ignored? Is this a one-time thing?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that all of the cells in question begin with two characters which are to be ignored, you could use an Array Formula.

If your data (from your example) is in cells `A1:A5`, then you could use Array Formula:

```
=SUM(VALUE(MID(A1:A5,3,99)))     → → →     [CTRL]+[SHIFT]+[ENTER]
```

Copy the formula above and paste it into the formula bar.

Since it's an `array formula`, ***instead of hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>***, you need to **hold down <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> and then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>**.

[image: img]

---

### More Information:

- Office Support : [**Guidelines and examples of array formulas**](https://support.office.com/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7)
- Office Support : [**Create an array formula**](https://support.office.com/article/create-an-array-formula-e43e12e0-afc6-4a12-bc7f-48361075954d)
- Office.com : [**`MID` Function** (Excel)](https://support.office.com/article/mid-midb-functions-d5f9e25c-d7d6-472e-b568-4ecb12433028)
- Office.com : [**`VALUE` Function** (Excel)](https://support.office.com/article/value-function-257d0108-07dc-437d-ae1c-bc2d3953d8c2)

Comment: Is there another alternative to this? I keep getting #VALUE! error

Comment: Rather than trying alternatives, it's best to try copying this one exactly and getting it working.  Put the same data in the same spot and try again (including the CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER instead of ENTER), and it should work fine, and then you can try adapting it to your actual data.

Comment: I clarified the instructions above

Comment: @joon25 - Were you able to get it figured out?